# How to transfer files from Android to Windows without using ADB?

Tags: recovery-mode, lock-screens, file-transfer, windows

The phone is locked and I can't turn Wi-Fi or Bluetooth on. So, I need to find a way to transfer files to Windows. Is there a way to do it? I have found third party softwares but I will apply them as a last resort. Besides, the phone doesn't turn off and I can't use ADB cause I don't know the directories where the files are located

Comment: Why is it locked ?

Comment: For using adb you don't have to know file paths you can simply list files via `ls` in `adb shell`. More important is if adb is activated and your PC is authorized to use adb on the phone.

Comment: @RohitGupta owner of the phone passed away and no information about screen lock

Comment: @Robert I didn't know that point thank you, but i tried adb and it wasn't activated